# How to make this breadth first search faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, search

I have a search algorithm that looks for combinations of add and multiply functions to reach a certain range of number from a certain range of numbers. It is searching for the shortest program, a program being a something like AAMMA where the initial number is added, added, multiplied, multiplied, add where the ending number is in the range r to s. It has to work for every number in the starting range p to q.

The input is a and m, what you are adding and multiplying by(num+a), (num*m) for each function. What I am doing is trying every combination of functions until I find one that works, stopping that branch if it gets too big. If I find "program" that works I try the program on all of the other numbers in the starting range. It does this until either it finds no branches that don't reach the range without going over.

I know the search isn't super typical, but I don't think there is a possibility for duplicates so I didn't include a found list.

It works for smaller ranges and inputs like

```
Problem3("1 2 2 3 10 20")
```

but for larger ranges, it just takes forever my test case is

```
Problem3("8 13 28 91 375383947 679472915")
```

which I haven't even seen complete. What is my best approach from here, multithreading(hope not), making my inner functions faster somehow or just scraping this approach.

```
def Problem3(s):
    a,m,p,q,r,s = list(map(int, s.split(" ")))

    print(str(a) + "-C-" + str(m) + " processor")
    print("Input guarenteed between " + str(p) + " and " + str(q))
    print("Output is real number between " + str(r) + " and " + str(s))

    open_set = queue.Queue()
#   curr path depth
    open_set.put([p, "", 0])

    while not open_set.empty():

        subroot = open_set.get()

        multiCurr = subroot[0] * m
        addCurr = subroot[0] + a
        depth = subroot[2] + 1

        if r <= addCurr <= s:
            truePath = True
            #If we find a working path, we need to check if it works for the other things
            path = subroot[1] + "A"
            for x in range(p, q+1):
                for op in path:
                    if op == "A":
                        x += a
                    if op == "M":
                        x *= m
                if r <= x <= s:
                    pass
                else:
                    truePath = False
                    break
            if truePath:
                print("Found " + path + " at depth " + str(depth) + " with starting number " + str(p) + ", output " + str())

        if r <= multiCurr <= s:
            truePath = True
            path = subroot[1] + "M"
            for x in range(p, q+1):
                for op in path:
                    if op == "A":
                        x += a
                    if op == "M":
                        x *= m
                if r <= x <= s:
                    pass
                else:
                    truePath = False
                    break
            if truePath:
                print("Found " + path + " at depth " + str(depth) + " with starting number " + str(p) + ", output " + str())

        if addCurr > s and multiCurr > s:
            pass
        elif multiCurr > s:
            open_set.put([addCurr, subroot[1] + "A", depth])
        elif addCurr > s:
            open_set.put([multiCurr, subroot[1] + "M", depth])
        else:
            open_set.put([multiCurr, subroot[1] + "M", depth])
            open_set.put([addCurr, subroot[1] + "A", depth])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to test every value in the `range(p, q + 1)` sequence. You only need to test for `p` and `q`. If it works for the lowest and the highest number, it'll work for all the values in between, because the problem has been reduced to just multiplication and addition. You really only need to test the progress of `program(q)`, keeping it below `s`, until you have created the shortest program that puts `program(p)` at or above `r`.

However, this isn't really a great problem for breath-first search; your second example would require testing 17.6 *trillion* possible states; the shortest solution is 44 characters long, so a breath-first search would explore 2 ** 44 states, so 17,592,186,044,416 to be exact! Even using a compiled programming language like C would take a long, long time to find the solution using such a search. Instead, you can just generate the string using a bit of math.

You can calculate the maximum number of multiplications needed here with `int(math.log(s // q, m))`, that's the number of times you can multiply with `m` when starting at `q` and still stay below `s`. You can't ever use more multiplications! With `math.ceil(math.log(r / p, m))` you can find the minimum number of multiplications that would put `p` at or above `r`. To minimise the program length, pick the lower value of those two numbers.

Then, start fitting in `A` additions, before each `M` multiplication. Do so by taking `i` as the number of `M` characters that are to follow, then dividing both `r` and `s` by `m ** i`. These inform the number `a` additions to `p` and `q` that together with the subsequent multiplications bring it closest to `r` and `s`; the difference with the current `p` and `q` let you calculate the minimum number of `A` characters you can insert here to keep within the `[r, s]` range. For `p`, round up, for `q`, round down.

Repeat this procedure for every subsequent `M` operation, updating the `p` and `q` values with the results each time:

```
import math

def problem3(s):
    a, m, p, q, r, s = map(int, s.split())
    p_mult = math.ceil(math.log(math.ceil(r / p), m))
    q_mult = int(math.log(s // q, m))
    mult = min(p_mult, q_mult)
    program = []
    for i in range(mult, -1, -1):
        p_additions = math.ceil((math.ceil(r / (m ** i)) - p) / a)
        q_additions = ((s // (m ** i)) - q) // a
        additions = min(p_additions, q_additions)
        program += [additions * 'A']
        if i:
            p, q = (p + (additions * a)) * m, (q + (additions * a)) * m
            program += ['M']
    return ''.join(program)
```

This is a closed-form solution, no search needed. The result is guaranteed to be the shortest:

```
>>> problem3("1 2 2 3 10 20")
'AMM'
>>> problem3("8 13 28 91 375383947 679472915")
'AAAAAAMAAMAAAAAAAAAAAMAAAAAMAAAMAAAAMAAAAAAA'
```